# Any effective opensource alternative for New Relic for Java

Tags: open-source, performance-testing, application-server

Is there any effective opensource alternative available for `New Relic` for the `Java` platform (particularly for monitoring J2EE application servers *like* `JBoss`)?

Comment: +1 Looking for the same thing - there must be something about, Ive found pinba - http://pinba.org/ which may help you but its no good for what I want

Comment: Looks like `pinba` is specific for `MySQL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though it does not have all the features of new relic, you can take a look at [stagemonitor](http://www.stagemonitor.org/). It is a open source java web application performance monitor. It captures response time metrics, JVM metrics, request details (including a call stack captured by the request profiler) and more. The overhead is very low.

Optionally, you can use the great timeseries database graphite with it to store a long history of datapoints that you can look at with fancy dashboards.

Take a look at the [project website](http://www.stagemonitor.org/) to see screenshots, feature descriptions and documentation.

Note: I am the developer of stagemonitor

Answer (score 0):

You can use javamelodyfor monitoring JBoss.

http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at RHQ http://www.jboss.org/rhq

"RHQ is an enterprise management solution for JBoss middleware projects, Tomcat, Apache Web Server, and numerous other server-side applications.
RHQ provides administration, monitoring, alerting, operational control and configuration in an enterprise setting with fine-grained security and an advanced extension model."